# Is there a programmatic way to switch Azure Role monitoring from Minimal to Verbose?

Tags: azure-diagnostics

All I need is a way to force my role to use Verbose monitoring once it gets started. This needs to be automatic at deployment time.

An C# call would be ideal. Calling a cmdlet (e.g. Set-AzureDiagnosticsBlabla -Level Verbose) is also OK. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this PowerShell command:
**Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495270.aspx

Also, there is a good reference for configuring diagnostic for Azure Cloud services.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx

Comment: I could not find any way to set monitoring level to Verbose. Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension will change settings which I already have set in diagnostics.wadcfgx file. AFAIK, that file won't change monitoring from Minimal to Verbose.